# Criar um SlideShow somente com Html e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: Modelo/Exemplo do Slide]

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Projeto 01</title>

<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentDiv(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
         dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="topo">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Redes Sociais</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="esquerda"></div>
    <div class="direita">
        <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
          <img class="mySlides" src="img/01.png">
          <img class="mySlides" src="img/02.jpg">
          <img class="mySlides" src="img/03.jpg">
          <div class="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
            <div class="w3-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
            <div class="w3-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    background: white;
    display: both;
}
.topo {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: teal;
    box-shadow: 0 0 08px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.topo p {
    color: #000; 
}
.topo ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
.topo li {
    float: left;
}
.topo li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topo li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
.conteudo {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 04px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 05px 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: both;

}
.conteudo p {
    color: #000; 
}
.esquerda{
    width: 15%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: ;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 30px;
    border-radius: 03px;
    float: left;
    }
.direita {
    width: 15%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: ;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 30px;
    border-radius: 03px;
    float: right;
} 

#rodape p {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px; 
}
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
```

Possuo pouco conhecimento na área de desenvolvimento. Conheço apenas o básico em Html e CSS (não sei javascript ou jquery). 
Mas ainda sim, preciso criar um pequeno slide para um projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

- Preciso adicionar as imagens em uma pequena DIV lateral, em que exiba apenas uma imagem e uma legenda/descrição logo abaixo NÂO sobrepondo a imagem;
- Com botão de Próximo e Anterior;
- A legenda/descrição precisa ser atualizada junto a imagem;
- Preciso saber como esconder as imagens e fazê-las aparecerem em determinado tempo;
- Fiz pesquisas, mas não obtive conhecimento ou entendimento sobre;
- Como se trata somente de Html e CSS, não se encontra muito na internet;
- Num livro que estava lendo **CSS - do iniciante ao profissional** Li sobre *Overflow* e *animation*. Mas não sei  como aplicá-los;
- E até agora não sei como devo construir a estrutura para tal;

Comment: Tem um exemplo na W3School muito bom <br/>
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp Trabalha com CSS e javascript puro, e não precisa instalar plugins ou jquery. O que ajuda no desempenho.

Answer (score 3):

A criação de um slider apenas utilizando CSS sem requerer o uso de Javascript para nos dar um maior controlo de eventos consoante a interação do usuário, é um conceito um pouco complexo. Mas no entanto possível de se fazer.

Eis alguns plugins que encontrei após ter feito uma breve pesquisa:

> - [PureCssSlides](https://github.com/littleli/PureCssSlides) - Página de demonstração [aqui](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/demos/nojs/)
> - [Responsive CSS3 Slider](http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/)
> - [Basic CSS Image Slideshow](http://www.cssscript.com/basic-image-slideshow-with-pure-css/) - Página de demonstração [aqui](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/basic-image-slideshow-with-pure-css/)

Aqui abaixo tens a maneira mais simples de criar um simples slider apenas com CSS, que se auto inicia, usando `animations`. ([codepen](http://codepen.io/blackMec/details/JNdRWY/))

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #e9e1c1;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
a {color: #19838d;}

.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding-bottom: 28%;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 15px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  margin: 40px auto 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #777;
}

.photoWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.photo {
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}
p.photoDescr {
  background-color: #8e8e8e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

@keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.photoWrapper:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.photoWrapper:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.photoWrapper:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.photoWrapper:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
@media (max-width: 728px) {
  .container {
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="photoWrapper">
        <img class='photo'  src="//c1.staticflickr.com/1/624/32968186751_a913f86f82_c.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="photoWrapper">
        <img class='photo'  src="//c1.staticflickr.com/3/2868/33027057984_13609393e8_c.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="photoWrapper">
        <img class='photo'  src="//c1.staticflickr.com/3/2913/33895858336_33c5124502_c.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="photoWrapper">
        <img class='photo'  src="//c1.staticflickr.com/3/2923/33100532164_31bac14009_c.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

> Podes tambem ver outra solução funcional mais visual com botões <kbd>prev</kbd>, <kbd>next</kbd> etc exatamente como querias **sem requerer o uso de Javascript** e onde podes ter uma idea de como trabalhar o código CSS para criar tal funcionalidade: [CSSdeck - Pure css slider](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-slider-target)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*transition*/
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
body {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle, #f0f0f0, #74a9ad);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, circle, #f0f0f0, #74a9ad);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, circle, #f0f0f0, #74a9ad);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, circle, #f0f0f0, #74a9ad);
    background: radial-gradient(center, circle, #f0f0f0, #74a9ad);
    padding: 50px;
}
/* Slider */
.slider {
    height: 250px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -125px -225px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    width: 450px;
    /*box-shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.slider .frames {
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
.slider .frames .slide {
    height: 250px;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
}
.slider .slide:target { z-index: 100 }
.slider .frames .slide img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 450px;
}
.slider .frames .slide nav a {
    background: hsla(0,0%,0%,.75);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
.slider:hover .frames .slide nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.slider .frames .slide nav .prev {
    /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
    border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
    left: 0;
}
.slider .frames .slide nav .next {
    /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
    border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
    right: 0;
}
.slider .frames .slide nav a:hover { background: #000 }
.slider .quicknav {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.slider:hover .quicknav { opacity: .9 }
.slider .quicknav li { display: inline-block }
.slider .quicknav a {
    background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
    border: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.9);
    /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 10px;
}
.slider .quicknav a:hover { background: hsla(0,0%,50%,.9) }
.slider #one:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#one"], .slider #two:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#two"], .slider #three:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#three"], .slider #four:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#four"], .slider #five:target ~ .quicknav a[href="#five"] {
    background: hsla(0,0%,0%,.9);
    border-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
    background: rgb(244,246,245);
    /*linear-gradient*/
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(rgba(244,246,245,1),0.01),color-stop(rgba(203,219,219,1),1),color-stop(rgba(216,216,216,1),1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%, rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%, rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%, rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%, rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(244,246,245,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(203,219,219,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(216,216,216,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%,rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%,rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%,rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(244,246,245,1) 1%,rgba(203,219,219,1) 100%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f4f6f5', endColorstr='#d8d8d8',GradientType=0 );
    /*box-shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000,0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5),0 2px 3px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000,0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5),0 2px 3px #666;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000,0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5),0 2px 3px #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="frames">
        <li id="one" class="slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/250/animals" alt="Slide 1">
            <nav>
                <a class="prev" href="#five">&larr;</a>
                <a class="next" href="#two">&rarr;</a>
            </nav>            
        </li>
        <li id="two" class="slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/250/sports" alt="Slide 2">
            <nav>
                <a class="prev" href="#one">&larr;</a>
                <a class="next" href="#three">&rarr;</a>
            </nav>            
        </li>
        <li id="three" class="slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/250/nature" alt="Slide 3">
            <nav>
                <a class="prev" href="#two">&larr;</a>
                <a class="next" href="#four">&rarr;</a>
            </nav>            
        </li>
        <li id="four" class="slide">
            <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/450/250/food" alt="Slide 4">
            <nav>
                <a class="prev" href="#three">&larr;</a>
                <a class="next" href="#five">&rarr;</a>
            </nav>            
        </li>
        <li id="five" class="slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/250/animals" alt="Slide 5">
            <nav>
                <a class="prev" href="#four">&larr;</a>
                <a class="next" href="#one">&rarr;</a>
            </nav>            
        </li>
        <li class="quicknav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#two"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#three"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#four"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#five"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa!! Meu amigo!!! Muito obrigado, Vou testar todos aqui.

Comment: Bom, muito obrigado. Funcionou bem os slides; Agora preciso descobrir como implementar, a descrição a DIV e atualiza-la junto a imagem

Comment: Um exemplo de como o fazer no ultimo exemplo: [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/ttga5953/)